# Php: Running a python script using blender from a php project using cmd commands

Tags: php, python, blender

I need to run in cmd a python script for blender from blender and print the result from a php project, but I don't get the all result.

Here is my code:

```
$script = "C:\Users\madalina\Desktop\workspace\script.py";
$blander_path = "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender";
$output = shell_exec("cd $blander_path && blender -b -P script.py -- $json");
print_r($output);
```

and here is what I receive:

**found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.69\python Blender quit**

And here is what i get when i run the same script directly from my cmd
[image]

How can a get the same response when I when the same script from my php project?
(I use blender 2.69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem. I changed the system_exec command with exec, put the json object in quotes.

this is my code now:

```
$json = str_replace("\"", "\\\"",  json_encode($jsonArray));
$script = "C:\Users\madalina\Desktop\workspace\script.py";
$blander_path = "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender";
$output = exec("cd $blander_path && blender -b -P $script -- \"$json\"", $data);
print_r($data);
```