# Running a blender script on linux hosting

Tags: php, python, linux, blender

I am currently working on a web app which spits out a .stl file in blender. I have used php and I am calling the script in php using exec(). Please look at the code below. I found the code from 
[Php: Running a python script using blender from a php project using cmd commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563809/php-running-a-python-scrip-using-blender-from-a-php-project-using-cmd-commands)

```
$script = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test.py";
$blender_path = "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender";

$output = exec("cd $blender_path && blender -b -P $script", $data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

And all works well locally. I uploaded the content to my site(Linux hosting), Uploaded Blender(Linux - https://www.blender.org/download/) changed the paths and nothing happens. It doesn't even output any errors. Is there a separate command line code for linux? I am not used to using Linux and I have been struggling with this for the past 3 days.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities. The first is the path names, on linux there is no drive letters a path should be something like `/home/aniket/tests/blendtest`

The second relates to running a program, I would expect an error but you may have to look into log files to find it or increase the verbosity of php. The first point is that a file needs permissions set to be executable, this would involve `chmod +x blender` or maybe using your ftp software to set this, it is often represented as `X` within a permissions string like `RWXRWXRWX`. The second point is the way commands are found on a *nix system, there is a PATH environment variable that lists directories to look for a command, the current directory is not in that list by default and I wouldn't expect a hosting company to add it.

```
$script = "/home/aniket/test1/test.py";
$blendexe = "/home/aniket/blender2.76/blender";

$output = exec("$blendexe -b -P $script", $data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

On *nix systems `./` represents the current directory, so you may also have luck using

```
$output = exec("cd $blender_path && ./blender -b -P $script", $data);
```